# file_get_contents() doesn't work on concrete website

Tags: php, html, curl

I'm trying to get HTML content from website www.pornhub.com (don't ask why :D) but classic

```
file_get_contents('http://www.pornhub.com');
```

doesn't work. I have also tried

```
$Url = 'https://www.pornhub.com/categories';

if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
    die('CURL is not installed!');
}
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $output;
```

but it doesn't work either.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

thx for any help.

Comment: What error message do aou get?

Comment: Do other websites work?

Comment: their terms specificity ask you not to scrape them, and they are actively trying to stop you- so um stop

Comment: Typically this is cross origin error and you can not request content unless they configure cross origin allowance to respond your url

Comment: @PashaB That would only apply from a client-side script (like JavaScript)

Comment: @Dagon or so you've been told, right ;)

Comment: @phil no i was wanking to the terms earlier today - they are hot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kindly try this one:

```
$Url = 'https://www.pornhub.com/categories';

if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
    die('CURL is not installed!');
}
$ch = curl_init($Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // add this one, it seems to spawn redirect 301 header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13'); // spoof
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $output; // use echo to show contents
```

Comment: This works perfectly thank you very much, maybe you helped to future big porn site :D

Comment: @user13746 actually it was hard for me to test this if this is working since it will output the site and im in the office haha

Comment: yea  that could be a little bit awkward situation, to try them explain that you are solving someones problem :D